# Display the city with the shortest and longest name

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing a question where I have been told:

"Query the two cities in the table with the shortest and longest city names, as well as their respective lengths (i.e.: number of characters in the name). If there is more than one smallest or largest city, choose the one that comes first when ordered alphabetically."

I am running the following code, however it keeps saying my answer is wrong:

```
SELECT CITY, LEN FROM (

SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) AS LEN, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LEN, CITY ASC) as r
FROM STATION ) as a

WHERE r IN (1, (select count(*) from a))
```

Why does that not work?

Comment: Also note you're using LEN as an alias in your orderby of your row_number.  While  MySQL may allow this; most other RDBMS engines do not as they occur at the same level or at the same order of operation.  MySQL,  undocumented as far as I cold find in the past,; seems to allow one to use aliases so long as they are used after it in the select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` twice to get the city with min and max length:

```
SELECT t.CITY, t.LEN 
FROM (
  SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) LEN, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY), CITY) as rn1,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) DESC, CITY) as rn2
  FROM STATION 
) t
WHERE 1 IN (t.rn1, t.rn2)
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vcsw91UAbHYk5qM9m5NmUB/0).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use

```
select  a.CITY,  t.max_len,  b.CITY,  t.min_len
from  (
    SELECT max(LENGTH(CITY)) max_len , min(LENGTH(CITY)) min_len 
    FROM STATION 
) t 
INNER JOIN STATION a ON a.LENGTH(CITY) = t.max_len  
INNER JOIN STATION b ON b.LENGTH(CITY) = t.min_len
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it as two separate query and join it by `UNION ALL`.

```
(SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY)
FROM STATION
ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) asc, CITY asc
LIMIT 1)

UNION ALL

(SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY)
FROM STATION
ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) desc, CITY asc
LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this way also (MySQL):

```
SELECT city, length(city)
FROM station
ORDER BY length(city) ASC, city ASC limit 1;
SELECT city, length(city)
FROM station
ORDER BY length(city) DESC, city DESC limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

YOU COULD ALSO USE BY ORDER BY CLAUSE

-- Find city with shortest name

```
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) AS name_length
FROM STATION
ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) ASC, CITY ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

-- Find city with longest name

```
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) AS name_length
FROM STATION
ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) DESC, CITY ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't see how your answer is any different from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61756310/display-the-city-with-the-shortest-and-longest-name/76820709#76820709) - apart from the column alias. Did I miss something? Also, the question asks for a single query that returns both the longest and shortest names - and not two, separate queries as in your answer.